# How does the &= assignment operator work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone explain me how `&=` assignment operator works in Python programming.

Comment: Do you understand how `+=` works?  `&=` is exactly the same, except that it uses bitwise AND rather than addition as the operation being performed.  I don't know whether it's `&` you don't understand, or assignment operators in general.

Comment: `a &= b` is basically same as `a = a & b`

Answer (score 2):

&= is a bitwise and operator. It works with the binary number. I'll explain this to you by an example
Example:
x = 5 
In binary 5 is equal to 101
Now
x &= 3 which means x = x & 3 
You also need to convert 3 to binary number which is 011
Now you need to apply and operator to both binary number
  101
  & 011
=001

So now convert this resulting binary number to decimal number which is equal to 1.
You can use online converter from decimal to binary and binary to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

&= is a bitwise operator, it works with bits such as following,

```
a = 60            # 60 = 0011 1100 
b = 13            # 13 = 0000 1101 
c = 0

c = a & b;        # 12 = 0000 1100
print ("c: ", c)
```

output:

```
c: 12
```

It works on the basis of logic given below

```
0&0=    0
0&1=    0
1&0=    0
1&1=    1
```

look at the comments i have given in the code.

Comment: you're welcome it has been my pleasure to help you out! .and as there are two answers you should mark one of them as answer because it will help others in future.